# Use gitlab-ci variables in java sping boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, gitlab-ci

I would like to use predefined GitLab CI/CD variable -e gitlab-user-email="$GITLAB_USER_EMAIL" (that's a part of .gitlab-ci.yml file's deployment job) in my java spring boot application

My java code:

```
@Service
public class LocalEmailSenderStartupTest {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LocalEmailSenderStartupTest.class);

    @Value("${gitlab-user-email}")
    private String gitlabUserEmail;
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Write them to a properties file or something as part of the build, and include that on the classpath when you run it.

Comment: Hard to find information about this question!